# iOS equivalent of Android's Handler message queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, message-queue

Is there a standard way to build a message loop in iOS similar to Android's [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) where I can send simple integer messages to a handler on a background thread? I want the main thread to do as little work as possible. I want to avoid even creating an Objective-C block on the main thread to send to a dispatch queue as the blocks to be run are quite big.

Comment: you can just use `dispatch_async` on the background queue - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW2

Comment: @Paulw11 But that requires a block to be created from the main thread. Creating an "integer message" block just to tell it to create another task block seems ugly.

Comment: It requires a block to be created - but this is just a reference to compiled code.  When you call `dispatch_async` GCD will assign the code to a thread from the appropriate thread pool.

Comment: The other approach you can use is an `NSOperationQueue` - you can use a technique similar the one I outlined in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040915/managing-multiple-operations-in-single-nsoperationqueue-ios-like-pause-resume-si/29043782#29043782  Rather than using a simple boolean to pause/unpause you can use an NSMutableArray as a queue of work items with the NSOperation waiting for a signal when the queue is empty